# Asterisk: How to record more than one audio file per one call

Tags: audio, asterisk, recording

I want to record the call in asterisk with the loop one minute for each audio file. That means there are many audio recording files per one call but they have the length of 1 minute. For example, the recording file names for the call in 10 minuts are: audioRec1.wav, audioRec2.wav, audioRec3.wav, audioRec4.wav ... audioRec10.wav. 
Is it possible to do this in asterisk? if not, are there any program doing this job?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 options

1) Create external controller app, which will remember all record states and if callmore then minute do stopmonitor/startmonitor.

- Connect via ami http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API
- Stop call monitor  http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+StopMonitor
- Change name http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+ChangeMonitor
- Start new monitoring  http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Monitor

2) Change asterisk source code to do what you expect. Very complex,require guru levle in asterisk.

3) Record by asterisk Record app using chanspy in a loop, always changing files

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Record

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+ChanSpy

4) split file after end of file. this is very easy method.

Comment: Thanh you very much Arheops,

Comment: As for option 2, do you really implement new features by modify Asterisk source code? I won't suggest that to anyone unless he really want to get into Asterisk development

Comment: Sure, i am working with asterisk only for more then 10 years and do implement some features in C sometimes. If no way do it via dialplan. As i say, simplest is 4.